# Blender Texture bake not working

Tags: texture-baking, baking, error

I am trying to bake a texture into my model but it is not wanting to bake. I have followed all tutorials and it doesn't work and I can't find anyone with the same issue. The error I am getting is "no valid object selected" even though I have the image node and the model selected.
[image]

Comment: You have enabled Selected to Active so you need to select the one you want to bake then shift and select the one that bakes, is it the case?

Comment: No I selected the object and no matter if I push shift or not the node will be selected or unselected and I still get the same error

Comment: maybe pack your images and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/05c7fceb12ad46a3b26f7dc96db994b8 here you are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've activated the *Selected to Active* option which is used to bake from an object to another, while you actually want to bake the object to itself, so just deactivate and it will work fine:

[image]